# Proof of A superposition of stationary states is not a stationary state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, superposition, time-evolution

This is proof: ([Is the superposition of stationary states a stationary state? If not, then why not?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/211035/is-the-superposition-of-stationary-states-a-stationary-state-if-not-then-why-n))

A superposition of stationary states is not a stationary state. Suppose we have two kets, $| E_1 \rangle$ and $|E_2 \rangle$, which solve the TISE like so:
$$
\hat{H} | E_i \rangle = E_i | E_i \rangle
$$
Here, the left hand side is the Hamiltonian operator and and the right hand side just shows that the stationary state picks up an eigenvalue. This is the definition of a solution of the TISE, although you may be more familiar with the differential operator version which is equivalent to left-multiplying by a position eigenstate $\langle x |$. Now, suppose we create a new superposition state, $| \psi \rangle$, defined as:
$$
| \psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( | E_1 \rangle + | E_2 \rangle \right)
$$
If this is a solution to the TISE (that is, if it is a stationary state/eigenstate of the Hamiltonian) then it should follow that $\hat{H} | \psi \rangle = c | \psi \rangle$, where $c$ is a constant. But we can use linearity to write:
$$
H | \psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \hat{H} | E_1 \rangle + \hat{H} | E_2 \rangle \right) \\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( E_1 | E_1 \rangle + E_2 | E_2 \rangle \right)
$$
This is not a constant $c$ multiplied by the vector $| \psi \rangle$ *unless $E_1 = E_2$*. So we can see that two stationary states cannot be combined into another stationary state unless they share the same eigenvalue.

---

I have struggling understanding why $E_1 =E_2$ for the constant to be $c$ in the final line. Can anyone help expand the final line in more detail so that i can understand it better

Comment: Hint: If $E_1 = E_2$ then you can factor out $E_1$ from the expression. What happens when you bring this factor outside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an extremely drawn out proof of this simple fact:

Let's assume that $$E_1 | E_1\rangle + E_2 | E_2\rangle= c \left(| E_1\rangle + | E_2\rangle\right)\tag{1}\label{1}$$

(I've absorbed the $\sqrt{2}$ factor in the definition of $c$.) Now, bring everything to one side and you'll see that $$(E_1-c) | E_1\rangle + (E_2 - c) | E_2\rangle= 0.$$

However, since $|E_1\rangle$ and $|E_2\rangle$ are linearly indepedent (since they are both *different* stationary states), the only way that a linear combination of them is zero is if both the coefficients that multiply them are individually zero. In other words, the above equation means that:

$$E_1 = c,\\ E_2 = c,$$

i.e. $E_1 = E_2.$ In other words, this is the only way for Equation (\ref{1}) to hold.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly pointed out that in general a superposition of two eigenstates of a Hamiltonian is not an eigenstate itself. From the last line you showed we can see the following:

If $E_1=E_2$, then $$ H|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\, (E_1\, |E_1 \rangle + E_1 |E_2 \rangle) = E_1 \, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\, (| E_1 \rangle +| E_2 \rangle) = E_1 \, |\psi\rangle \quad, $$ which shows that $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $H$.

**Edit**: The converse holds true, too: Suppose that $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $H$, then $$ H|\psi\rangle = c\, |\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\, (E_1\, |E_1 \rangle + E_2|E_2 \rangle) \quad ,$$ for some  $c\in \mathbb{R}$. Multiplying from the left with e.g. $\langle E_1|$ leads to $$ c\, \langle E_1|\psi\rangle = \frac{c}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{E_1}{\sqrt{2}} $$ and thus $c=E_1$. The same must be true for the state $|E_2\rangle$ and hence $c=E_1 =E_2 \quad .$